# Determine if all jQueryUI checkboxes(buttons) are unchecked

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, checkbox

I have a series of jQueryUI checkboxes rendered by html like the following...

```
<input class="asset-tile-select-input" id="asset-tile-select-input-84" type="checkbox"
name="asset-tile-select">
<label for="asset-tile-select-input-84"></label>
```

And I make them go with...

```
$("input[id*='asset-tile-select-input']").button(
{
    text: false
});
```

Then, whenever (I thought) the box is un/checked, I use the following to determine if I should show/hide a related element...

```
$("input[id*='asset-tile-select-input']").change(
function()
{
    if( $("input[id*='asset-tile-select-input']:checked") )
    {
        alert("asdf");   
        if( $("#box-asset-icon-container").is(":visible") == false )
        {
            $("#box-asset-icon-container").show(300);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if( $("#box-asset-icon-container").is(":visible") == true )
        {
             $("#box-asset-icon-container").hide(300);
        }
    }
});
```

Only, the alert fires whether I check or uncheck the box. WHY?  It works one way, in that it will .show() the related element if something's checked.  How do i set this up so it knows whether all like checkboxes are not checked and in turn hides the related #box-asset-icon-container element?

Comment: where is box-asset-icon-container in your html?

Comment: i don't think the actual _value_ is changing, which is what `.change()` looks for.

Comment: #box-asset-icon-container is in an entirely different node branch than the checkboxes.

Comment: @yak613 - ok, this is why I'm here.  Do you know what it should be?

Comment: This condition will **always** evaluate to `true` regardless of your actual HTML: `if( $("input[id*='asset-tile-select-input']:checked") )`. This is because it returns a jquery container, which when typecast to boolean is `true` even if the container's empty. Perhaps you meant to use `.length`, but it's a bit unclear. Could you describe exactly what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `$("input[id*='asset-tile-select-input']:checked")` is an object. Use `$("input[id*='asset-tile-select-input']:checked").length > 0` instead